# Yield to maturity / IRR in Power Query M

Tags: excel, powerquery

Do you have any ideas about how to calculate YTM / IRR in Microsoft Power Query? 
For instance, I have a variable called Table and it contains data

```
    Date        Payment
    2020-01-01  -1000
    2020-02-01  300
    2020-03-01  800
```

and I would like to call some scalar function, which calculates YTM.

Comment: Can you show your formula for YTM that you'd like to use?

Comment: Actually there is no formula. YTM is a solution of equation like `sum(i=0 to n)(B_i / (1+ytm)**i) = 0`. Equation is convex and is easily solved numerically in imperative programming languages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like now the only way is to solve this equation yourself. I've found code in this [blog post](https://www.thebiccountant.com/2017/05/23/goal-seeking-and-xirr-in-powerbi-and-powerquery/). I have a laptop with Win 10, Excel 2016, i3-6100 2.3GHz, 4 ram. It takes 0.10 sec to calculate for deal with 10 payments.